# Expand and collapse row on button click which is in a td in mat table row

Tags: angular, mat-table

```
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

                <!-- Document Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="document">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Document </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let search; let i = index">
                        <button mat-button (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === search ? null : search">Show
                            Log</button>
                        <!-- {{search.document}} -->
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                    <!-- more containers -->
        <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let search" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
                    <div class="example-element-detail"
                        [@detailExpand]="search == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
                        <div class="example-element-description">
                            <div class="">
                                <div class="">
                                    <pre> {{search.document}</pre>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let search; columns: displayedColumns;" class="example-element-row"
                [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === search"
                (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === search ? null : search">`enter code here`
            </tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
        </table>
```

I have a mat-table with a button in a column in every row (as shown in shared code above). I am looking for expanding and collapsing the row (one at a time) on button toggle.

content in ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
//other component imports
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({height: '0px', minHeight: '0'})),
      state('expanded', style({height: '*'})),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['document', 'timestamp', 'conversationId', 'microserviceName', 'responseStatusCode', 'host', 'clusterName', 'elapsedDuration'];
//other useful declarations
  expandedElement: SearchResponse | null;

  // set observables into datasource using MatTableDataSource
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<SearchResponse>();

  constructor(private appService: AppService,
                    private toastr: ToastrService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    //service call
  }
  //service call and functions
}
```

Unable to find out why button toggle is not working and row is expanded by default.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Noted @halfer.. Will refrain from using such phrases in my questions going forword. Thankyou!..

Comment: you has a Table with expandable rows? is the 4th example in the docs: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: @Eliseo , yes idid go through that example in angular material.. but i need to expand and collapse by a button toggle in that row instead of the complete row. Just dont know how to do it here.

Comment: just  write `<button mat-button (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">Show Log</button>`. When you want a unique row expanded at time, you use a unique variable -in the example the variable is "expandedElement"-

Comment: @Eliseo i changed the button code as you have highlighted above and followed 4th example in the docs: material.angular.io/components/table/examples.. the row is expanded by default and button toggle is not working. Unable catch what mistake i have done.

Comment: @Eliseo i have modified my question with my current html and ts file code for better visibilit as to what i have done.

Comment: @RashmiChoudhary, you need add some css to your search.component.css, see my answer

Comment: @Eliseo: Thanks a million! This worked exactly how i wanted it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need add to your search.component.css

```
tr.example-detail-row {
  height: 0;
}
.example-element-detail {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}
.example-element-row td {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

And remove the (click) in row

```
//this
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let search; columns: displayedColumns;" 
     class="example-element-row"
     [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === search"
     (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === search ? null : search">
      `enter code here`
</tr>
```

become as

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let search; columns: displayedColumns;" 
   class="example-element-row"
   [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === search">
</tr>
```

See this [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzwqmw?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html)