# Angular Material table select row but more data needed

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a material table that having an array as datasource. But from what I experienced, if we select a row and within this row variable only contains data that being displayed on the table, what if I need to select the specific index of object from the array and pass to other screen? Can I select more than row variable? Thanks

Comment: in a mat-table, you choose the  displayed columns, but the data source can store more variables than columns. More, you can use `<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let rowSelected;" (click)="yourFunction(rowSelected)">` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60990643/expand-and-collapse-row-on-button-click-which-is-in-a-td-in-mat-table-row/61008649#61008649 (in this SO is for expanded a row, but you can use for anything), or you can use `<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i=index">` to get the index, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292349/get-index-of-row-in-angular-material-table-v5

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but seems like that 2 links not really helping because they are still passing row, I want the datasource itself to be pass. Let say index 2 object in datasource is selected,  I want this whole index 2 objected selected and pass to a function, not the the row info

Comment: dataSource[index]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

  selectedRow(row) {
    console.log('selectedRow', row)
  }
}

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  age: number;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H', age: 20},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He', age: 20},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li', age: 20},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be', age: 20},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B', age: 20},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C', age: 20},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N', age: 20},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O', age: 20},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F', age: 20},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne', age: 20},
];
```

app.component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selectedRow(row)"></tr>
</table>
```

Notice - in object I am getting 5 property while in table showing only 4. Once you will click on any row in table in `selectedRow()` method you can get complete object of that row.

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-select-row)

click on any row and check console, you will get data.

Let me know if you still have any issue.